Matplotlib unable to render Chinese characters
I am trying to plot graphs using matplotlib with labels and titles written in Mandarin (Chinese). However matplotlib renders them as boxes. I have tried the following approaches to try to solve the problem:

Include magic line # -*- coding:utf8 -*- (no effect)
Use pyplotz library (error/no effect)
Specify unicode (u"smth") (no effect)

Can somebody help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much!
Edit: I am using Mac OS Sonoma, with Python 3.12 and Matplotlib 3.8.4.
Simplified version of code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
plt.title("例子")
plt.plot(..., label="例子"）
plt.show()


Does this answer your question? How do you i use mandarin characters in matplotlib?

Hi @TinoD! I tried similar ways to solve the problem, but no, this doesn't solve my problem because I am using Mac. Also, I am not using subplots. The fontproperties attribute is not supported in Pyplot methods like title and plot. But thanks anyway!

Adding the following code after the import matplotlib.pyplot as plt may help you solve the problem.
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif']=['SimHei']
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False 


I downloaded SimHei.ttf and moved it into the matplotlib font folder (/Users/...../Library/Python/3.12/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf) and added the code but still doesn't work. Warning lines keep telling me that the font isn't found is printed repeatedly in the terminal and the characters still end up as boxes. (findfont: Generic family 'sans-serif' not found because none of the following families were found: SimHei). Thanks for trying though.
